# Better crit chance or crit damage or something else?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I have found when ROS went out a legendary ring with this stats:

- 429 vit ( rerolled )
- 94 all res
- 7.0% atk speed

I don't remember which stat I rerolled into vit but I do remember I had only 4M thoughness so I was forced to find some survivability somewhere in the gear. 
Now I can reach 9.0M thoughness, so I feel confident to reroll vit again into crit chance or crit damage.
I don't have any spreadsheet and I'm too lazy to do the math so I'm asking:
Which stat is better to look for? Will I get more dps with 6.0% **crit chance** or with 50% **crit damage**? Is it better, indeed, **min-max damage** or some plain **dex** - using Seize the iniziative as passive it could balance dps and thoughness?

**Edit:**
Crit chance: 30.5%
Crit damage: 392%

Comment: "I don't have any spreadsheet and I'm too lazy to do the math so I'm asking".  The problem is the answer is entirely gear dependent.  If you have 10000% crit damage already (exaggeration) but 5% crit chance, then of course the 6% crit chance is better, but if you have 99% crit chance and 50% crit damage, then the other is better.

Comment: Sure, I forgot to add some infos. Editing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much crit chance, and crit hit damage you already have, the rule of thumb here is that you want to have **1 crit hit damage** for every **0.1% crit hit chance**.
Additionally, dex would be better if you had a very low dex at the moment and a very high crit hit chance/damage, but i don't expect that to be the case here.

Edit: with your stats you should aim for crit hit chance

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hope to not waste tons of forgotten souls in order to get a good roll :P

Comment: if you had my luck it would take you 25 souls atleast xD